# Cross compiling from OSX section in eLinux.org is wrong

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi

http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation#Get_the_kernel_source

It says 
Complete script requires raspberrypi.config to be in the same folder that you execute from

```
#Make a case sensitive 3gb disk image, raspberrypi-kernel, and attach it

hdiutil create -size 10g -type SPARSEBUNDLE -nospotlight -volname raspberrypi-kernel -fs "Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+" -attach ./raspberrypi-kernel.dmg
cp raspberrypi.config /Volumes/raspberrypi-kernel/
mkdir /Volumes/raspberrypi-kernel/src
cd /Volumes/raspberrypi-kernel/src
```

========================================================================

That Scriot won't work because it's creating volume on the Raspberry Pi.   It says secpificailly this is for crossing-compiling on a mac for Raspberry Pi. That script won't run on a Mac for sure.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: So go report this to the website!

Comment: Do you agree it's wrong like I perceived?

Comment: No. The script is correct - `/Volumes/raspberrypi-kernel` is a disk image named "raspberrypi-kernel" on the local machine.